# Order issue of component using sklean.mixture.GaussianMixture

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture to do classify a set of 2D data into 3 component, I want use blue for component 1, red for component2 and green for component3. I use a for loop to deal with 8 group of data in different files. However, I cannot get a consistent color for each group. [image: for this one, the color order is green-blue-red][image: For this one, the color order is green-red-blue] 
I want to make the order sequence consistent for all the figures.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
import itertools
import matplotlib as mpl



file_list_x1=["1.txt","2","3.txt","4.txt","5.txt","6.txt","7.txt","8.txt"]

color_iter = itertools.cycle(['blue', 'red', 'green'
                              ])
def perform(filename):

    X=np.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header=1)

    gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=3).fit(X)
    means=gmm.means_
    var=gmm.covariances_
    lables = gmm.predict(X)


    ax1=plt.subplot(111)    
    #ax1.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=labls, s=20,cmap='brg')

    print filename
    print "Mean is:"
    print means
    print "\n\nvar is:"
    print var

    for i, (mean, cov, color) in enumerate(zip(gmm.means_, gmm.covariances_,
                                               color_iter)):
        v, w = np.linalg.eigh(cov)
        if not np.any(lables == i):
            continue
        ax1.scatter(X[lables == i, 0], X[lables == i, 1], 20, color=color)

        # Plot an ellipse to show the Gaussian component
        angle = np.arctan2(w[0][1], w[0][0])
        angle = 180. * angle / np.pi  # convert to degrees
        v = 2. * np.sqrt(2.) * np.sqrt(v)
        ell = mpl.patches.Ellipse(mean, v[0]*1.2, v[1]*1.2, 180. + angle, color=color)
        ell.set_clip_box(ax1.bbox)
        ell.set_alpha(.2)
        ax1.add_artist(ell)
        ax1.set_xlim([0,150])
        ax1.set_ylim([0,25])        
    plt.show()


for each in file_list_x1:
    perform(each)
    print"\n\n\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clear way to do it with scikit-learn because there is no common thing for 2 model. However, if you expect to see similar cluster in similar location, then you can compare them yourself.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

def generate_2_cluster():
  length = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
  angle = np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 2, 100)
  c1 = np.array((length * np.cos(angle), length * np.sin(angle))).T
  length = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
  angle = np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 2, 100)
  c2 = np.array((2 + length * np.cos(angle), 2 + length * np.sin(angle))).T
  X = np.vstack((c1, c2))
  return X

X = generate_2_cluster()
gmm1 = GaussianMixture(n_components=2).fit(X)
Y = gmm.predict(X)

plt.scatter(X[:, 0][Y==0], X[:, 1][Y==0], c="blue")
plt.scatter(X[:, 0][Y==1], X[:, 1][Y==1], c="red")
plt.show()

X = generate_2_cluster()
gmm2 = GaussianMixture(n_components=2).fit(X)
Y = gmm.predict(X)

d0_to_0 = np.linalg.norm(gmm1.means_[0]-gmm1.means_[0])
d0_to_1 = np.linalg.norm(gmm1.means_[0]-gmm2.means_[1])
if d0_to_0 < d0_to_1:
  plt.scatter(X[:, 0][Y==0], X[:, 1][Y==0], c="blue")
  plt.scatter(X[:, 0][Y==1], X[:, 1][Y==1], c="red")

else:
  plt.scatter(X[:, 0][Y==0], X[:, 1][Y==0], c="red")
  plt.scatter(X[:, 0][Y==1], X[:, 1][Y==1], c="blue")

plt.show()
```

Here I compare mean values and consider two pair the same cluster if their mean distance is closer than other pair. You may also need to compare covariance matrices.

[image]

[image]